# Youtube in a scrolling div causing weird glitch in Chrome

Tags: javascript, flash, object, google-chrome, youtube-api

So, this is a wierd glitch I can't really put into words to describe. However I will try.

Right now there's a youtube object for use of the Youtube player API that is above a div that has scrolling. These two elements are in different divs and are not connected in any way. The youtube in the scrolling div is a standard iframe player. When I scroll up, the iframe seems to scroll up and right into the object, showing whatever is behind the object (in this case an image that is the background), despite that fact that both are in thier own individual divs and aren't overlapping.

I "fixed" this problem by getting rid of the -type="application/x-shockwave-flash"- from the object, however doing that means that I can't trigger events using the youtube api.

This error only occurs in Google Chrome, I have used this in both IE and Firefox, and it doesn't cause this weird intersecting issue. The client needs this to work in Chrome.

Thank you very much for your time,

-Supreme

Comment: You should post an example file/URL for us to check out. Let us see what's happening first-hand. Chrome can be awfully strange sometimes. :)